# How to display vim-test output in a quickfix window?

Tags: filetype-python, plugin-vim-test

I have installed [vim-test](https://github.com/vim-test/vim-test), and setup the following pytest executable in my `.vimrc`:

```
let g:test#python#pytest#executable = 'python3 -m pytest'
```

When I call `:TestFile`, pytest runs in a background shell and display errors. But I would like to display those errors with file names and line numbers in a quick fix window that can be used to jump to the file at that line number.

The vim test readme mentions several quickfix-strategies:

https://github.com/vim-test/vim-test#quickfix-strategies

Is there a way to simply display the errors in a quickfix window, without creating a makefile?

Comment: I added `let test#strategy = "dispatch"` to `.vimrc` so that the test output appears in a vim split (using `tpope/vim-dispatch`). But it still doesn't provide the link to jump to line numbers within files.

Comment: Have you tried 'make' strategy?

Comment: Thanks `let test#strategy = "make"` does create a link to the particular line in the file, but the split disappears when pressing enter on that file & line number. I am used to a quick fix window, for example when calling ":Git grep", files and line numbers are display and remain after clicking on them.

Comment: You might try `:copen` after one of those strategies. There are also a few commands (cbuffer?) that can create a quickfix list from arbitrary buffers/files/expressions

Answer (score 1):

In `.vimrc`, define strategies to send the test output

```
let test#strategy = "make"
" or
" let test#strategy = "dispatch"
```

After running [vim test](https://github.com/vim-test/vim-test)'s `:TestFile` or `:TestSuite` on a [pytest script](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/usage.html), use `:copen` to display the test result in a quickfix window. Lines of the errors that contain a file name and a line number will create a link that directly sends you to the file and line where the error occurred.